# Deep check for two python dictionaries and get the difference in report form

Tags: python

Say There are two dictionaries in python -

### Dict1

```
mydict1 = { 
        "Person" :
            {
                "FName"    : "Rakesh",
                "LName"    : "Roshan",
                "Gender"   : "Male",
                "Status"   : "Married",
                "Age"      : "60",
                "Children" :
                    [
                        {
                            "Fname"    : "Hrithik",
                            "Lname"    : "Roshan",
                            "Gender"   : "Male",
                            "Status"   : "Married",
                            "Children" : ["Akram", "Kamal"],
                        },
                        {
                            "Fname"    : "Pinky",
                            "Lname"    : "Roshan",
                            "Gender"   : "Female",
                            "Status"   : "Married",
                            "Children" : ["Suzan", "Tina", "Parveen"]
                        }
                    ],
                "Movies" : 
                    {
                        "The Last Day" :
                            {
                                "Year" : 1990,
                                "Director" : "Mr. Kapoor"
                            },
                        "Monster" :
                            {
                                "Year" : 1991,
                                "Director" : "Mr. Khanna"
                            }
                    }
             }
    }
```

### Dict2

```
mydict2 = {
        "Person" :
            {
                "FName"    : "Rakesh",
                "LName"    : "Roshan",
                "Gender"   : "Male",
                "Status"   : "Married",
                "Children" :
                    [
                        {
                            "Fname"    : "Hrithik",
                            "Lname"    : "Losan",
                            "Gender"   : "Male",
                            "Status"   : "Married",
                            "Children" : ["Akram", "Ajamal"],
                        },
                        {
                            "Fname"    : "Pinky",
                            "Lname"    : "Roshan",
                            "Gender"   : "Female",
                            "Status"   : "Married",
                            "Children" : ["Suzan", "Tina"]
                        }
                    ]
             }
    }
```

I want to compare two dictionaries and print the difference in report format as below -

```
MISMATCH 1
==========
MATCH DICT KEY : Person >> Children >> LName
EXPECTED  : Roshan
ACUTAL    : Losan


MISMATCH 2
==========
MATCH LIST ITEM : Person >> Children >> Children
EXPECTED        : Kamal
ACTUAL          : Ajamal


MISMATCH 3
==========
MATCH LIST ITEM : Person >> Children >> Children
EXPECTED        : Parveen
ACTUAL          : NOT_FOUND

MISMATCH 4
==========
MATCH DICT KEY  : Person >> Age
EXPECTED        : 60
ACTUAL          : NOT_FOUND 

MISMATCH 5
==========
MATCH DICT KEY  : Person >> Movies
EXPECTED        : { Movies : {<COMPLETE DICT>} } 
ACTUAL          : NOT_FOUND
```

I tried with Python module called datadiff which does not give me a pretty output in a dictionary format. To generate the report I have to traverse dictionary and find '+' '-' keys. If the dictionary is too complex then its hard to traverse.

Comment: How are you expecting the lists to be handled? Does the order matter?

Comment: I do no expect an order of the list... I am expecting **1.** Both the lists should have equal number of elements **2.** All elements in list1 should be there in the list2 and vice-verse, irrespective of an order of the elements.. SO I AM NOT EXPECTING to have elements in order

Comment: Should this be a database instead of a dict perhaps?

Answer (score 6):

**UPDATE:** I've updated the code to deal with lists in a more appropriate way.  I've also commented the code to make it more clear if you need to change it.

This answer is not 100% general right now, but it can be expanded upon easily to fit what you need.

```
def print_error(exp, act, path=[]):
    if path != []:
        print 'MATCH LIST ITEM: %s' % '>>'.join(path)
    print 'EXPECTED: %s' % str(exp)
    print 'ACTUAL: %s' % str(act)
    print ''

def copy_append(lst, item):
    foo = lst[:]
    foo.append(str(item))
    return foo

def deep_check(comp, compto, path=[], print_errors=True):
    # Total number of errors found, is needed for when
    # testing the similarity of dicts
    errors = 0

    if isinstance(comp, list):
        # If the types are not the same then it is probably a critical error
        # return a number to represent how important this is
        if not isinstance(compto, list):
            if print_errors:
                print_error(comp, 'NOT_LIST', path)
            return 1

        # We don't want to destroy the original lists
        comp_copy = comp[:]
        compto_copy = compto[:]

        # Remove items that are both is comp and compto
        # and find items that are only in comp
        for item in comp_copy[:]:
            try:
                compto_copy.remove(item)
                # Only is removed if the item is in compto_copy
                comp_copy.remove(item)
            except ValueError:
                # dicts need to be handled differently 
                if isinstance(item, dict):
                    continue
                if print_errors:
                    print_error(item, 'NOT_FOUND', path)
                errors += 1

        # Find non-dicts that are only in compto
        for item in compto_copy[:]:
            if isinstance(item, dict):
                continue
            compto_copy.remove(item)
            if print_errors:
                print_error('NOT_FOUND', item, path)
            errors += 1

        # Now both copies only have dicts

        # This is the part that compares dicts with the minimum
        # errors between them, it is expensive since each dict in comp_copy
        # has to be compared against each dict in compto_copy
        for c in comp_copy:
            lowest_errors = None
            lowest_value = None
            for ct in compto_copy:
                errors_in = deep_check(c, ct, path, print_errors=False)

                # Get and store the minimum errors
                if errors_in < lowest_errors or lowest_errors is None:
                    lowest_errors = errors_in
                    lowest_value = ct
            if lowest_errors is not None:
                errors += lowest_errors
                # Has to have print_errors passed incase the list of dicts
                # contains a list of dicts
                deep_check(c, lowest_value, path, print_errors)
                compto_copy.remove(lowest_value)

        return errors

    if not isinstance(compto, dict):
        # If the types are not the same then it is probably a critical error
        # return a number to represent how important this is
        if print_errors:
            print_error(comp, 'NOT_DICT')
        return 1
    for key, value in compto.iteritems():
        try:
            comp[key]
        except KeyError:
            if print_errors:
                print_error('NO_KEY', key, copy_append(path, key))
            errors += 1

    for key, value in comp.iteritems():
        try:
            tovalue = compto[key]
        except KeyError:
            if print_errors:
                print_error(value, 'NOT_FOUND', copy_append(path, key))
            errors += 1
            continue

        if isinstance(value, (list, dict)):
            errors += deep_check(value, tovalue, copy_append(path, key), print_errors)
        else:
            if value != tovalue:
                if print_errors:
                    print_error(value, tovalue, copy_append(path, key))
                errors += 1

    return errors
```

With your dicts as input I get:

```
MATCH LIST ITEM: Person>>Age
EXPECTED: 60
ACTUAL: NOT_FOUND

MATCH LIST ITEM: Person>>Movies
EXPECTED: {'The Last Day': {'Director': 'Mr. Kapoor', 'Year': 1990}, 'Monster': {'Director': 'Mr. Khanna', 'Year': 1991}}
ACTUAL: NOT_FOUND

MATCH LIST ITEM: Person>>Children>>Lname
EXPECTED: Roshan
ACTUAL: Losan

MATCH LIST ITEM: Person>>Children>>Children
EXPECTED: Kamal
ACTUAL: NOT_FOUND

MATCH LIST ITEM: Person>>Children>>Children
EXPECTED: NOT_FOUND
ACTUAL: Ajamal

MATCH LIST ITEM: Person>>Children>>Children
EXPECTED: Parveen
ACTUAL: NOT_FOUND
```

The way lists are compared has been updated so that these two lists:

```
['foo', 'bar']
['foo', 'bing', 'bar']
```

Will only raise an error about 'bing' not being in the first list.  With string values the value can either be in the list or not, but an issue arises when you are comparing a list of dicts.  You'll end up with dicts from the list that do not match to varying degrees, and knowing what dicts to compare from those is not straight forward.

My implementation solves this by assuming that pairs of dicts that create the lowest number of errors are the ones that need to be compared together.  For example:

```
test1 = {
        "Name": "Org Name",
        "Members":
        [
            {
                "Fname": "foo",
                "Lname": "bar",
                "Gender": "Neuter",
                "Roles": ["President", "Vice President"]
                },
            {
                "Fname": "bing",
                "Lname": "bang",
                "Gender": "Neuter",
                "Roles": ["President", "Vice President"]
                }
            ]
        }

test2 = {
        "Name": "Org Name",
        "Members":
        [
            {
                "Fname": "bing",
                "Lname": "bang",
                "Gender": "Male",
                "Roles": ["President", "Vice President"]
                },
            {
                "Fname": "foo",
                "Lname": "bar",
                "Gender": "Female",
                "Roles": ["President", "Vice President"]
                }
            ]
        }
```

Produces this output:

```
MATCH LIST ITEM: Members>>Gender
EXPECTED: Neuter
ACTUAL: Female

MATCH LIST ITEM: Members>>Gender
EXPECTED: Neuter
ACTUAL: Male
```

Comment: This looks good. However, do you consider the lists in order?
In above example, it may be possible that Children[1] in dict1 could be Children[0] in the dict2..